# How to find out number of entries in initializer-list at compile-time?

Tags: c, initializer-list

I have the following code:

```
#define DEF1 "first"
#define DEF2 "second"
#define INIT_LIST { DEF1, DEF2 }
```

Is there any way to get number of entries in INIT_LIST at compile time?

Comment: This has the smell of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)... What is the actual and underlying problem you need to solve? Why do you need to get the number of elements at compile-time? Why do you think it will solve your problem? Always ask about the actual problem directly.

Comment: Presumaly you'll do sth like `char *arr[] = INIT_LIST;` and then you can do `sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]` which can be a compile-time operation.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I need to implement mechanism that builds OpenCL C sources from files specified in INIT_LIST, so user will be able to specify functionality which they want to use.

Comment: @WeatherVane Good one, but I have already tried it. I need to specify it in header, but this is definition and it must be in .c file.

Comment: If you try doing all this malarky in macros you might end up with unreadable code.

Comment: Maybe consider auto-running some script to generate the sources before compilation. Most IDEs support that and it's cleaner to do all such generation separately instead of using the C preprocessor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a char-pointer array of unknown size and initialized using INIT_LIST as a compound literal to `sizeof`. Then divide by `sizeof` char-pointer and you get the number of elements in INIT_LIST.

Like

```
#define INIT_LIST_ELEMENTS (sizeof((char*[])INIT_LIST) / sizeof(char*))
```